# Can I run a .bp/.meta graph generated by single node tf.sess on a distributed environ with multi-ps/worker nodes?

Tags: tensorflow

Will future versions of tensorflow provide a way to run the tensorflow graph generated by single node tf.sess on a distributed environments with multiple ps nodes and worker nodes through python interfaces?
Or is it supported right now?

I am trying to build my tf.graph on my notebook (single node) and save then graph into a binary file, 
and then loading the binary graph into a distributed environment (with multiply ps and worker nodes) to train and verify it. It seems it is not supported now.

I tried it on tensorflow-0.10 and failed.
By using

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, path, pb_name)
```

interface: The graph saved is not trainable as loading the `.pb` file through `import_graph_def` will only `g.create_ops` according to the `.bp` file but not add then into `ops.collections`. So the graph loaded is not trainable.

By using `tf.saver.save` to save a `.meta` file: The loaded graph cannot fit into the distributed environment as devices assignment is messy.

I tried the

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph('test_model.meta', clear_devices=True)
```

interface to let the load clean the original device assignment and let the `with tf.device(device_setter)` reassign the device for each variable, but there is a problem as operations belonging to `Saver` and `Restore` still can not be assigned correctly. When creating operations for `Saver` and `Restore` ops through `g.create_op` inside `import_graph_def` called by `import_meta_graph`, the device_setter will not assign ps node to these ops as their name is not `Variable`.
Is there any way to do so?